# RequireJS and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, internet-explorer-9

I've tried to find the solution in previous questions but i couldn't.
I have a web project developed in jquery using requireJS. Everything seems to work fine (in all modern browsers) until i tested in IE9 where there isn't a script working. I tried to find the cause but all i can get is the feedback from dev tool console:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error libCommon.js, line 10 character 3
>
> SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action libEvents.js, line 5
>   character 2

This is the beginning code of libCommon.js:

```
//generic JS for all views
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    var LibCommon = function () {};

LibCommon.prototype.hideSubmenu = function() {
    $submenu.removeClass('show');
}

LibCommon.prototype.toggleSubmenu = function(tipo) {
    const $tipoSubmenu = $('#'+tipo);
    this.hideSubmenu();
    if (!$tipoSubmenu.hasClass('show')) {
        $tipoSubmenu.addClass('show');
    } else {
        $tipoSubmenu.removeClass('show');
    }
};

//and other functions...
```

And this is the beginning code of libEvents.js:

```
//generic JS for all views
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap', './libCommon', 'modernizr'], function ($, Bootstrap, LibCommon, Modernizr) {


var common = new LibCommon();
/**
 * =================
 * TO EXECUTE WHEN INIT
 * =================
 */
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log('initialized all common events');

    var common = new LibCommon();

    // Fixed header  
    var stickyNavTop = $('.topmenu').offset().top;
    common.fixedNav(stickyNavTop);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        common.fixedNav(stickyNavTop);
    });

// and other functions or events...
```

In both errors it's first character of creating a variable/instance of an object after defining all objects/dependencies in requireJS, so it shouldn't be an error. I tried by changing for `var common = 0;` but error continues appearing in console. It seems that IE9 doesn't like any script. Otherwise, require's instances are working because bootstrap is working properly. Any idea?

Comment: IE9 doesn't support ES6, so I'm thinking it's the `const $tipoSubmenu = $('#'+tipo);` line that bugs everything, since IE9 doesn't recognise const. Do you have modernizr or a different shim so you can use ES6 syntax?

Comment: You were right. Deleting const line makes all js code loaded succesfully and IE9 interprets all JS. It is a pity IE9 console doesn't give you the correct line of the error so I was lost finding it. Thank you @Shilly

Answer (score 0):

[Shilly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038647/requirejs-and-ie9#comment65426723_39038647) already pointed out in a comment that you should not pass ES6 constructs to IE9. Either write ES5 or use a tool to transpile it.

Now, the error you are getting in `libEvents` is bizarre because `libCommon` should not have loaded at all, and consequently the factory of `libEvents` should not run because one of the dependencies did not load. It is possible to have a module load *and* later give errors. But I don't recall ever seeing a *syntax error* in the immediately-interpreted code of a module that did not just cause the load to fail. (The code you are showing is *interpreted* immediately, even if it is *executed* later. If you had an `eval(string_of_code)` in there or a `Function(string_of_code)` then `string_of_code` would be interpreted later but this is not something that happens in your code.) I suspect the reason RequireJS goes ahead with executing the factory for `libEvents` has to do with a problem catching load failures in IE9 and lower. The [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#ieloadfail) suggests turning on `enforceDefine`. I would do this for your code. This won't solve everything but it may help RequireJS detect problems better.

`console.log` will also probably give you troubles, as explained by [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746119/requirejs-not-working-in-ie9).

Comment: I was completely lost due to the way of IE9 compiles my JS. I couldn't understand how libEvents.js could be loaded without libCommon.js was loaded properly as you mention. I read the requirejs documentation and tried to turn on enforceDefine but i didn't get the solution to solve my problem. Thanks for your time @Louis